# Prevent submitting a form and show error message if 2 combo boxes contain the same value

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, power-platform

I have 2 combo-boxes inside a canvas app form named Approver1 & Approver2 >> where both fields represents a SharePoint "People/Group" field

Now I want to make sure that the Approver1 will be different than Approver2.

And I need to prevent submitting the form if the 2 combo boxes have the same user/value + to show a message under each field if the 2 combo boxes have the same value?

Is this possible? and how?

Comment: Is this a standalone canvas app or customized list form? Combo boxes are single selection or multiple selection?

Comment: In order to better help you solve the problem, can you provide some more detailed description?

Comment: @GaneshSanap thanks for the reply.. this is a standalone cavas app + comboboxes are single selection thanks

Comment: check my answer given below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For single selection combo box controls in Power Apps, you can compare values using their properties via `.Selected` property.

**For example**:

For combo box with person or group column, you can compare values based on the selected user emails.

You can set add a label control in your app and set it's `Text` property to:

```
If(ComboBox1.Selected.Email = ComboBox2.Selected.Email, "Same", "Different")
```

**Output**:

1. When same person selected:

   [image]
2. When different person selected:

   [image]

---

You can use similar comparison for your formulas in other places.

1. You can set `Visible` property of label control which shows error message to:

```
ComboBox1.Selected.Email = ComboBox2.Selected.Email
```

2. You can use formula like below in `OnSelect` property button control which saves form in list:

```
If(
    ComboBox1.Selected.Email = ComboBox2.Selected.Email,
    Notify("Please select different Approvers.", NotificationType.Error),
    SubmitForm(Form1)
)
```

Comment: ok thanks worked for me